# Using href and Tocify toc

Tags: html, href, tableofcontents, jquery-tocify-js

I am using Tocify to make a TOC and I'm having some trouble.
In this TOC I have: "chapter 1", "chapter 2"...

In my site there are some places when I say "See chapter 1".
I have to include "a href" to "chapter 1" in my "See chapter 1" html text.
But I don't know what I have to write in that "a href=#....".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is done as follows:

Basically you need to set an ID to a element you want to reference. Then you can write:

```
<a href="#id">See chapter ID</a>

<h2 id="chapter1">Chapter 1</h2>
<p>Your paragraphs</p>
<p> ... </p>
<a href="#chapter2">See chapter 2</a>

<h2 id="chapter2">Chapter 2</h2>
<p>Your paragraphs</p>
<p> ... </p>
<a href="#chapter1">See chapter 1</a>
```

Hope this helps you.

**EDIT:**

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var link = $('#linkId');

  var chapter = $('#chapterId');
  var position = chapter.position(); // according to jQuery api
  var offsetTop = position.top; // this should be the absolute offset of the page's top

  // Calls the tocify method on your HTML elements.
  link.tocify();
  chapter.tocify();

  //Call the tocify method with options
  link.tocify({
    showEffect: "fadeIn"
    scrollTo: offsetTop, 
    smoothScroll: false
  });
```

- You cannot use tocify and #-href's at the same time because as you saw they override the url. So you have to use a jQuery or tocify method (see api's) to scroll to the specific element.
- Or you may don't want to use tocify on links.

Comment: Thank you. It's a great solution. But it changes the #url that it's generated through Tocify when TOC is created. It would be possible to get that tocify's #?

Comment: I can somehow understand what you mean but you may show me the code that you use?

Comment: With Tocify I get http://host/mysite/main.html#Chapter2:TheTitle when I click on the "Chapter 2: The Title" in my TOC (generated with Tocify). That #Chapter2:TheTitle is automatically generated with Tocify.
If I write <h2 id="chapter2">Chapter 2</h2>....<a href="#chapter2">See chapter 2</a> (it works) when I click on "See chapter 2" then I will get http://host/mysite/main.html#chapter2. 
I would like to know if it's possible to use/get the same # that is generated by Tocify.